# Scuplting in z direction only

Tags: sculpt

I'm following along with a blender guru tut in sculpt mode and as I use the sculpt tool it only seems to work in the z direction. When i sculpt on a horizontal face it works, but when I try on a vertical face it makes these weird divots that don't look right. https://youtu.be/GliQFJMVdY4

Answer (score 1):

Found it! my scale was not reset to 1, 1, 1. Simply go to object mode, ctrl+A, and click "scale" to reset. nice..